# How to set true as default for DataGridCheckBoxColumn in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am using a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` within a `DataGrid` like:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn/>
<DataGrid.Columns/>
```

But it has no `IsChecked` property.

How to set `IsChecked = true` as default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already said there is no `IsChecked` property for the [DataGridCheckBoxColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcheckboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx), because the `IsSelected` you are looking for is the `Binding` property.

> **Binding**: Gets or sets the binding that associates the column with a property in the data source.(Inherited from DataGridBoundColumn.)

---

So answering your Question:

> How to set IsChecked = true for default

There is no out of the box way to set the default value to `true`, because the default value of your property you are binding to your is `false`.

*[Default values table (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table)*
`default(bool)` is always `false` and you cannot override it

**But** you can set the property your are binding to the column within your class constructor to `true`.